# IF syntax error

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement, syntax, syntax-error

I'm getting a syntax error while following the MySQL guide for `IF` syntax.

My query is:

```
if 0=0 then select 'hello world'; end if;
```

Logically, this should select `'hello world'`, but instead I get

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'if (0=0) then select 'hello world'' at line 1
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'end if' at line 1
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your query is only valid in a stored procedure/function context.
See [there](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/if.html) for reference.

Answer (score 2):

using if statements like this is valid only inside stored procedure or functions.

What you'd probably like to use is the [if()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if) function, and then you can use:

```
select IF(0=0, 'hello world','');
```

Answer (score 0):

If statements are not supported in general SQL flow. It can only be used in functions or procedures. However you can use it in following way

```
use my_db;
delimiter #
create procedure xyz()
 begin
   IF 0=0 then select 'hello world';
 end if;
end#
```

Comment: why not just use the built in IF() function?

Comment: yeah it is possible but I have answered as per the context of question as I got it!