# SQL (1064) : IF

Tags: sql, if-statement, xampp

1064 error when executing query with the following code:

```
IF (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM arrest WHERE player = 0) > 0 THEN SELECT * FROM arrest END IF
```

Can anyone help me please with getting this to the right format?
Thank you very much!

Comment: which database you are using?

Comment: @Rohan XAMPP SQL

Comment: Possible duplicate of [IF syntax error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35366493/if-syntax-error)

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly sure what you're looking for but it might be this:

```
SELECT * FROM arrest
WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM arrest
              WHERE player = 0)
```

This code will select all records from the `arrest` table but only if one or more of those records has `player = 0`. If that condition isn't met, then the query will still run but will return no rows.