# mariadb have been reported error for "end if"

Tags: mysql, mariadb

I have an SQL statement has been reported 1064 errors,please help!

```
UPDATE `MessageQueue`
SET `Status`= 0, `RetryCount`= `RetryCount`+ '1', `LastRetryTime` = NOW(), `CanBeRemoved`=1
WHERE `MsgHash`= 1 AND `Status`=0;
SET @retVal = ROW_COUNT();
IF (@retVal = 0) THEN
    UPDATE `MessageQueue` SET `Status`= 5 WHERE `MsgHash`= 1;
    END IF;
SELECT @retVal;
```

this is after execute :
(1 row(s) affected)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:016
Total Time     : 00:00:00:016

(0 row(s) affected)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:015
Total Time     : 00:00:00:015

错误码: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 2
------- in there ,if delete ";" in "UPDATE `MessageQueue` SET `Status`= 5 WHERE `MsgHash`= 1;" this error will disappear   -------
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

错误码: 1064
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'end if' at line 1

Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

(1 row(s) returned)
Execution Time : 00:00:00:000
Transfer Time  : 00:00:00:000
Total Time     : 00:00:00:000

Comment: this's the sql:                                                                                                     UPDATE MessageQueue SET Status= 0, RetryCount= RetryCount+ '1', LastRetryTime = NOW(), CanBeRemoved=1 WHERE MsgHash= 1 AND Status=0;
SET @retVal = ROW_COUNT();
IF (@retVal = 0) THEN 
    UPDATE MessageQueue SET Status= 5 WHERE MsgHash= 1;
 END IF; 
SELECT @retVal;

Comment: `if` (in this way) can [only be used in a stored program](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35366493). Is this inside a stored procedure (and if yes, does this happen when you try to run the procedure, or when you try to create the procedure)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of questions:

- What version of MariaDB are you using?.
- Are you invoking your sentences from a stored procedure or an anonymous block (BEGIN NOT ATOMIC)?.

I can't reproduce the problem from an anonymous block:

```sql
BEGIN NOT ATOMIC
  UPDATE `MessageQueue`
  SET `LastRetryTime` = NOW()
  WHERE `Status` = 1;

  SET @`retVal` := ROW_COUNT();

  IF (@`retVal` = 0) THEN
    UPDATE `MessageQueue`
    SET `Status`= 5
    WHERE `Status`= 0;
  END IF;
END;
```

See [dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mariadb_10.4&fiddle=521cd17a4a5cebefa49a0b9d6bf1df43).

Comment: Thanks for you answer! The problem has already been solved，and your answer it's ok,Thanks again!