# Define IF-THEN statements within labels

Tags: mysql, sql, if-statement

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/35366493/4999991), consider that you want to do multiple things if a condition is met. pseudocode:

```
if condition then
    do things
else if other conditions then
    do other things
else
    other things
end if
```

From [this page](https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-if-statement/) one could define the if statement within a dummy procedure:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS <procedure_name>();
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE <procedure_name>()
BEGIN
    IF (<conditions>) THEN
        -- do things
    ELSEIF (<conditions>) THEN
        -- do other things
    ELSE 
        -- other things
    END IF;
END$$

DELIMITER ;

<procedure_name>();
```

which is honestly the ugliest way of implementing an if statement I have ever seen in any programing language, ever!

[This page](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/control-flow-functions/if-function.php) suggests some one-liner if statement syntax in the form of

```
SELECT IF(<condition>, 'true message', 'false message');
```

to print out messages or nested

```
SELECT <fields>
IF (<condition>)
AS <custom_label>
FROM <table>
```

to only select rows from a table that meet a specific condition of a specific field/column.

Now I was wondering if it is possible to implement if statements in a more canonical way. For example, using [labels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/statement-labels.html) to contain IF-THEN statements:

```
<label>: IF (<conditions>) THEN
    -- do things
ELSEIF (<conditions>) THEN
    -- do other things
ELSE 
    -- other things
END IF <label>;
```

or

```
<label>: BEGIN
IF (<conditions>) THEN
    -- do things
ELSEIF (<conditions>) THEN
    -- do other things
ELSE 
    -- other things
END IF;
END <label>;
```

which are slightly less ugly. The goal is to find a more sensible and concise way of defining if statements, so other solutions are also appreciated. Thanks for your support in advance.

Comment: 'to only select rows from a table that meet a specific condition of a specific field/column.' - that's a where statement but I don't really get what you are asking. You would have to use an if condition if you wanted to execute multiple statements based on a condition. Perhaps an example would help clarify.

Comment: In MySQL `IF` *statements* are only allowed in programming blocks, such as stored procedures, functions, and triggers.  That is how the language is defined.

Comment: @GordonLinoff isn't the `<label>` also a block? what other forms of code blocks are there?

Comment: @Foad . . . A block of code in MySQL starts with `BEGIN`.  In any case, the type of `if` that you are thinking of is rarely needed in SQL.  You are probably missing the point of "set-based" thinking.